# Why IDE and Unity consoles does not match?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, console, ide

I tried to use `or` in a script to summarize the condition, it does not show any problems in `Rider IDE` and the code is completely correct. But when I go to the Unity console window, as shown in the image, it gives irrelevant errors. This happens with some C# features and I don't know how to fix it. Please suggest how I can fix the problem.

```cs
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (name is "John" or "Mike" or "Ana") // or : no error in Rider but Unity Console Error
        {
            Debug.Log("This name pass");
        }

        List<string> names = new() {"X"}; // short list definition : no error in Rider but Unity Console Error
        
        names.ForEach(Debug.Log);
    }
}
```

### Rider IDE Console:

[image]

### Unity3D Console:

[image]

Comment: You need to use the supported c# options of ||

Comment: @BugFinderYes, I know that. Other ways are not difficult. My question is why the Unity console is not compatible with the IDE. thank you

Comment: Unity ide is compatible with its console.

Answer (score 1):

Rider and Unity have different compilers, so you can't expect Unity to use the newest C# features.

Your best call would be to change the API compatibility level in the player settings:

[image]

You can check official Unity documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html

Comment: It is true. I set it to net 4 but the problem is not solved. Does this mean that there is no way until Unity updates the compiler itself?

Comment: Yes, I guess there is nothing you can do at this point.